# How to avoid duplicate data in recyclarview when scrolling recycler view

Tags: android, hashmap, android-recyclerview

We are using recyclarview for first time. My problem is when scrolling recyclar duplicate data is adding to view. In Below Code:

```
public class ProductOptions_RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductOptions_ListRowHolder> {


    private ArrayList<Product_Details> storeItemList;
    HashMap<String, List<Product_Details>> product_items = new HashMap<String, List<Product_Details>>();
    private Context mContext;
    List<String> arrlist_skuitemName = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> arrlist_skuitemLabel = new ArrayList<String>();


    public ProductOptions_RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<String> arrlist_skuitemName, List<String> arrlist_skuitemLabel, HashMap<String, List<Product_Details>> product_items) {
        this.product_items = product_items;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.arrlist_skuitemName = arrlist_skuitemName;
        this.arrlist_skuitemLabel = arrlist_skuitemLabel;
    }


    @Override
    public ProductOptions_ListRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_productoptions, null);

        ProductOptions_ListRowHolder store = new ProductOptions_ListRowHolder(v);

        return store;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProductOptions_ListRowHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.name.setText(Html.fromHtml(arrlist_skuitemName.get(position)));
        holder.label.setText(Html.fromHtml(arrlist_skuitemLabel.get(position)));

        List<Product_Details> items = product_items.get(arrlist_skuitemName.get(position));

        Log.d("listdata","min postion"+position+" / "+items.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[items.size()];

            Product_Details pd = items.get(i);
            rb[i] = new RadioButton(mContext);
            rb[i].setTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#000000")));
            rb[i].setButtonTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#ff9900")));
            holder.rd_option.addView(rb[i]);
            rb[i].setText(pd.getName());

            TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            buttonParams1.gravity = Gravity.END;
            tv.setLayoutParams(buttonParams1);
            tv.setText(pd.getSalePrice());
            tv.setTextSize(15);
            //  tv.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT| Gravity.END);
            //holder.ll_priceitem.addView(tv);
            holder.rd_option.addView(tv);

        }

        holder.rd_option.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                int radioButtonID = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(radioButtonID);

                Toast.makeText(mContext,radioButton.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });



        View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ProductOptions_ListRowHolder tt = (ProductOptions_ListRowHolder) v.getTag();

                int pos = tt.getPosition();

            }
        };

        //Handle click event on both title and image click
        holder.rd_option.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

        holder.rd_option.setTag(holder);

//        notifyDataSetChanged();


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != product_items ? product_items.size() : 0);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }
}
```

In this Product_Details is a model class.Here we are trying to add radiobuttons dynamically based on service response i.e, added to HashMap(product_items).
When we are scrolling recyclar view automatic duplicates are adding.
For activity created data is correct.when scrolling duplicates adding.
Please Guide us, where we are going wrong?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: why dont you take all component in raw layout? you for loop causes problem i guess

Comment: Thanks for response,
Where we can use raw layout

Comment: you are adding views in `onbindviewholder` - why are you doing this? please google this site for proper recyclerview implementation, there is tons of it here.

Comment: @Pavan Alapati Refer [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/)